# Two inner DIVs side by side and one in center

Tags: css

There are two situations:
1. Two divs A & B in a container side by side
2. One div A in the same container in the center

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/lvil/toj9w9zz/

```
.container_one, .container_two {width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red;}
.container_one .inner_a {width:100px; background-color:green; float:left;}
.container_one .inner_b {width:100px; background-color:blue; float:right;}
.container_two .inner_a{width:100px; margin:0 auto; background-color:green;}

<div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_a">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="inner_b">
        b
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container_two">
    <div class="inner_a">
        a
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say the containers have the same class(not like in the example).
The number of inner DIV always changes (1 or 2).
Is it possible to make css fit both situations?
I have tried many things but could not achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use `display:inline-block` instead of floating and then target the divs with class `.inner_a` when they are the last child of the parent, like so:

```
.container_one>div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
.inner_a{
    background-color:green;
}
.inner_a:last-child{
    margin:0 auto;
}
.inner_b{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inline-block, keep this inner_a rules for both divs and remove floats.

```
.container_one, .container_two {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.container_two .inner_a {
  background-color: #008000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the best and least:

```
.inner_a  {
  background-color: green;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.container_one .inner_a  {
    float:left;
}
    .container_one,  .container_two  {
    width:200px;
     height:100px;
     background-color:red;
}

.container_one .inner_b  {
    width:100px;
     background-color:blue;
     float:right;
}
```